# How can I send multiple values of a HTML control (like list box) as parameter to fetch records to populate in my jTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-jtable

A typical way to load records from the server is by specifying parameters with the [load](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#met-load) method is this -

```
$('#PersonTable').jtable('load', { CityId: 2, Name: 'Halil' });
```

Now if I have to submit dynamic values by POSTing a form, I can POST details like this to generate a jTable -

```
$('#PersonTable').jtable('load', { $('CityId').val(), $('Name').val() });
```

where CityId and Name IDs of HTML controls

Now if City is list box that allows multiple selection of values, how should I reframe the above line so that it will POST multiple values for CityId to a server-side page that will process it.

Right now when I use this line where CityId is the Id of a List box -

```
$('#PersonTable').jtable('load', { $('CityId').val(), $('Name').val() });
```

the response body of the POST shows something like this -

**City%5B%5D**=4&**City%5B%5D**=1&**Name**=Halil

%5B%5D is equivalent to []

so this goes to my server side script as -

**City[]**=4&**City[]**=1&**Name**=Halil

I can retrieve the value for Name but not City when I try to fetch it using a method [like this](http://www.jtable.org/gettingstarted#ListAction) -

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PersonList()
{

}
```

How can I send multiple values of a HTML control (like list box) as parameter to fetch records to populate in my jTable

Answer (score 0):

Try using this to join the elements of an array into a string after checking that it doesn't contain a blank value -

```
$('CityId').val().join(",")
```